# Install Ubuntu 12.04 via 1GB usb?

Tags: 12.04

Is it possible to use a 1GB USB as an installer of Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. 12.04 remains 700mb-cd size,you can copy installation files to it and boot to install(extract ISO image)